# Uniqueness of $\partial_t u -u\Delta u=0$ with $u(0,\cdot)=1$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Is there anything known about uniqueness of classical solutions to
$$
\partial_t u -u\Delta u=0\quad u(0,\cdot)=1
$$
on smooth domains $[0,T]\times D$ without boundary conditions? I know that $u(0,\cdot)=0$ implies that $u=0$ even without boundary conditions.
However, does $u(0,\cdot)=1$ imply that $u=1$? It is not so hard to see that $\partial_t^k u(0)=0$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ if $u$ is smooth. Hence, for an analytic in time solution, this must be true.

Comment: With what boundary conditions?

Comment: No boundary conditions. I edited the question

Comment: Proving analyticity in time for a quasilinear parabolic problem? Good luck! :)

Comment: I don't need analyticity in time. Should just be a motivation that it could be true.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that there would be uniqueness without a boundary condition.  After all, if $D'$ is a small neighbourhood of $D$, one can non-uniquely smoothly continue the initial data $u(0,\cdot)$ from $D$ to $D'$.  Any classical solution to your PDE in $[0,T] \times D'$ would restrict to a classical solution in $[0,T] \times D$, and given the infinite speed of propagation for parabolic equations, this should give non-uniqueness in $[0,T] \times D$ (assuming existence of smooth solutions, of course).

Comment: In more physical terms, one can place an arbitrary heat source outside of $D$, and this will surely affect the temperature inside of $D$ at later times, leading to non-uniqueness for the linear heat equation $\partial_t u - \Delta u = 0$ in the absence of a boundary condition, and your quasilinear equation $\partial_t u - u \Delta u = 0$ for $u$ near $1$ will surely have very similar behaviour.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo Solution for parabolic equations are *almost never* analytic at $t=0$, even in the linear case.

Comment: @FanZheng You can even write *never*, for that matters, unless the parabolic equation is associated with a bounded linear operator. But then, I never claimed analyticity in 0 of anything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if one has  $\partial_n u=0$ or $u=1$ on $[0,T]\times \partial D$ it is relatively easy to prove that $u=1$ is the only regular solution.
This can be seen by observing that $e:=u-1$ satisfies
$$
\partial_t e -e\Delta e -\Delta e =0.
$$
Multiplication by $e$, the identity $\Delta e^2 = 2e\Delta e + |\nabla e|^2$, integration over the domain $D$, and Gronwall's lemma prove $e=0$.

Comment: At keast when $|e|<1/2$ (which holds on some nontrivial time interval $[0,T]$ for $T>.0$ by continuity